# Displaying a unicode character from SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, unicode

I have a listView which is populated by data from an SQLite database. One of my fields is a marker with a unicode character of either a full circle: \u25cf or open circle: \u25cb. Both characters display properly when I use a hardcoded string in a text field. However, in my listView I am seeing the text encoding instead of the character.

Does anyone know why this is... and how I get the unicode characters to display?

Thanks.

Update:

The insertion code is

```
private void loadRecords() throws IOException {
        final Resources resources = mContext.getResources();
        InputStream inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.records);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        try {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] strings = TextUtils.split(line, ",");
                if (strings.length <2) continue;
                long id = addRecord(strings[0].trim(),strings[1].trim(),strings[2].trim(),strings[3].trim(),
                        strings[4].trim(),strings[5].trim(),strings[6].trim());
            }
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
    }
```

with the resource being a csv file with one line being e.g.

```
primaryKey,name,surname,address,phone,email,\u25CB
```

Comment: because you don't insert it properly in the database.

Comment: What do you mean you're "seeing the text encoding instead of the character"? How exactly is it displayed?

Comment: I mean that the element in the lisView is displayed "\u25CB" instead of showing an open circle.

Comment: @njzk2 ... what is the correct way to insert it into the database then?

Comment: depends. post your insertion code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your text file, `\u25CB` are six characters.

To correctly use Unicode characters, put them directly into the file:

```
primaryKey,name,surname,address,phone,email,●
```

However, you must ensure that the .csv file has the same encoding as that used by your `InputStreamReader` (set the second parameter of its constructor).